# MySql permanent connection error `Unable to connect`

Tags: mysql, ado.net, mono, database-connection

-edit- nevermind, it was the bindaddress. But maybe you can explain why my php apps were able to connect? Or how to make it so i can connect via IP address OR 127.0.0.1. I certainly didnt configure, tell or update the sites to use my ip address instead of 127.0.0.1

I am using MySql on C# running on debian with mono. My app use to work. Then several things happened. I ran out of diskspace,  i changed a configuration so ibdata wasnt one big file. My db got full and ran out of disk space again. I also changed my bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to my machine IP address. My app use 127.0.0.1 but i'm unsure what the php sites use. I have a feeling i made other changes (such as having utf8 as the default) but i dont remember each of them.

I get the exception below. If i use `mysql -u user -p` I can login as said user. However my app still gets exceptions. I have no idea how i could debug this. What can i check and how might i fix this?

My sites in php seem to access the database. My one C# doesnt and my console app doesn't. They all use different usernames of course.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not user related.
"Unable to connect to **any of the specified MySQL hosts**"
To me it says that you have configured a (number of) MySQL host(s) that your app is trying to connect to - and failing. Most likely that you bind address change created this problem (why did you do it anyway?)
There may be a number of reasons why:
1) if your SQL server resides on computer with multiple network cards/connections your new configuration may have allowed connection on one of them but not the others.
2) AFAIR http clients were treated slightly differently to direct TCP clients, I think it had something to do with the way http servers were interpreting the SQL server address (I may be completely wrong on this one).

Comment: I adjusted the bindaddress so I can connect to a specific few databases remotely. I didn't expect it would ignore connections to 127.0.0.1. Php apps seem to be fine. Do you have any idea why? +1

Comment: I will try to run few tests later to check what I remember about it and post an update.

Comment: Thats ok. Maybe they just connect to a socket rather then ipaddress. Thats probably what it is. But i debug/build on windows so i use ipaddress rather then socket path

Comment: I figured it out. Its because other programs use `localhost` while i used `127.0.0.1`. Thats all there is to it. I simply test with mysql -h option